# Is there a method in recent Math.Net to return the SquaredNorm of a vector?

Tags: math.net

In the old version (Iridium) there was a method Vector.SquaredNorm() but in the most recent stable version of Math.Net there is none available.

What method should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the squared L2-norm (which is what Iridium did if I remember correctly) you can simply square it yourself:

```
var squaredNorm1 = Math.Pow(v.L2Norm(),2);
```

Alternatively you can also use dot product which is a bit shorter (and also faster in case you use native providers and the vectors are very large):

```
var squaredNorm2 = v*v;
```

Comment: In v2 L2Norm was not available yet - use `Norm(2)` instead

Comment: The reason for using a squared norm is efficiency.  Calculating a regular norm involves a square root operation, so SquaredNorm skips that step.  So the second suggestion is much preferred.